# how do I export environmental variables in my python script

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to code a discord bot in python.

I have saved my private bot token in .file

I intend to export the bot token temporarily as an environmental variable.

so my attempt looks like this

```
os.system('set -a')
os.system('source /path/to/.file')
os.system('set +a')
```

however, when I run printenv in console. the bot token does not show up!

funny thing is, if i were to run in console(zsh)

```
set -a
source .file
set +a
printenv
```

the bot token shows up nicely!

would appreciate if anybody could shed some light on this!

Comment: Environment variables flow solely from parent process to child process.  NOTHING you can conceivably do with `os.system()` will have any effect on the variables seen in a separate console window.  In fact, nothing you do with one `os.system()` will even be visible in another `os.system()` call; each one creates a separate child process.  You would have to do the `source` and the `printenv` in a single `os.sytem()` for this to work.  (But you really shouldn't be using `os.system()` in new code anyway, the `subprocess` module is preferred.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I can learn a lot from your comment. I will google and read this up!

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I recommend using [Dotenv library](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to import environment variables from file into python script using `load_dotenv` like below

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv('/path/to/.file')

ENV_VAR = os.getenv('ENV_VAR')
```

If not, I think you can also just read and parse the key-value manually instead provided that `.file` follows specific format like `.env` files

```
import os

with open('/path/to/.file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split('=', 1)
        # Maybe transform, parsing key value here
        os.environ[key] = value
```